# Why Array.map is (quite) faster than tail-recursive map?

Tags: ocaml

I write my tail-recursive version of `map_tail` like this:

```
let map_tail f l =
  let rec map acc = function
    | [] -> List.rev acc
    | hd::tl -> map (f hd :: acc) tl
  in 
  map [] l
```

And then an array based `map_by_array`:

```
let map_by_array f l =
  Array.of_list l |> Array.map f |> Array.to_list
```

---

Here is the benchmark code

```
let ran_list n =
  Random.self_init();
  let rec generate acc i =
    if i = n then acc
    else generate (Random.int 5::acc) (i+1)
  in 
  generate [] 0

let _ =
  let l = ran_list 10000000 in
  let f x = x+1 in
  let t1 = Sys.time() in
  let l1 = map_tail f l in
  let t2 = Sys.time() in
  let l2 = map_by_array f l in
  let t3 = Sys.time() in
  Printf.printf "map_tail: %f sec\nmap_by_array: %f sec\n" (t3-.t2) (t2-.t1)
```

---

I found that the array based map is faster, which surprises me a bit.

In `map_tail`, it traversals the list `twice` while `map_by_array` traversals list `three times`, why it is still faster?

Comment: Are you sure? I tried different scenarios, and for me, sometimes the first, sometimes the second is faster. Consider e.g. using `f x = Some (x+1)`. I think pure array traversal may be faster faster than list-traversal (since array probably occupies continous memory, and list has pointers).

Comment: Some details are discussed here: https://ocaml.janestreet.com/?q=node/71

Comment: @rafix yeah that article made me do this experiment

Comment: @phimuemue I did the experiment for `f x = Some (x+1)`, array based is even faster. `map_tail: 3.245189 sec, map_by_array: 2.242302 sec`

Comment: I also noticed it for prime-generation functions. When dealing with lists, it can take several hours to compute primes below 1 000 000 000, while with an array, only 12 seconds are needed. I guess this is due to memory allocation and garbage collection.

Comment: @FabianPijcke what prime-generation algorithm you are using?

Comment: Erathostene sieve, for which a list seemed accurate to me. Btw I only store 2; 3 and integers of the form 6 * k +/- 1.

Comment: @FabianPijcke if you use sieve, list is def much slower as you need `O(n)` for indexing, but array just need O(1).

Comment: @JacksonTale my first idea was, for each element x of the list, to filter the tail of the list, dropping any multiple of x (So I didn't need indexing at that point). I found later that actually I didn't need to know the values but that the indexes were enough, then I had a good reason to use arrays, and then I noticed how much faster it was :-p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It probably depends on the size of the list.

On long lists of size N, `map_tail` will do **2*N** allocations (N during the map, and then N for `List.rev`), while `map_by_array` will do **N+2** allocations (1 for the `Array.of_list`, 1 for `Array.map` and N for `Array.to_list`, that, actually, could be optimized to do only one allocation too).

Since allocations are probably the most expensive operations in this code, this difference should explain the difference of performance.